# Basic VBSCRIPT and HTML

Tags: html, vbscript

I am introducing myself into VbScript, can someone tell me what is wrong with my code? When I run it in IE the output is blank... I would expect the Hello World

E1: I am saving the file as .html

```
<html>

<body>

<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">

   document.write("Hello World!")

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `document.write()` is JavaScript and not VBScript. You just need to use tge following to display it on your browser:

```
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    document.write("Hello World!");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

But if you want to really use VBScript, then you need to use a supporting browser, which I feel I don't think there's any at the moment. Looks like you may need to turn on the feature before you can use it:

**VBScript in Internet Explorer**

Here are simple steps to turn on or turn off VBScript in your Internet Explorer:

- Follow **Tools » Internet Options** from the menu
- Select **Security** tab from the dialog box
- Click the **Custom Level** button
- Scroll down till you find **Scripting** option
- Select **Enable** radio button under **Active scripting**
- Finally click **OK** and come out

Comment: No, it is not Javascript. It is a call to a method of an object exposed by the host that executes the script. But the proper way to do it in VBScript is to remove the parenthesis

Comment: @MCND Thanks mate... But it looks like this is the proper way to do in VBScript as well. Weird that I am unable to work it out on my PC.

Comment: Hi Praveen. I tried doing what you suggested but it didn't work. I still see blank output.

Comment: @FranciscoJurado I see the right output here: http://jsbin.com/jamiwetupi/edit?html,output What browser are you using?

Comment: But is this still VBScript? I am trying to integrate VBScript with HTML. Using Internet Explorer. I am following this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vbscript/vbscript_syntax.htm

Comment: @FranciscoJurado, Like I told you, did you enable IE to use VBScript? I believe IE stopped supporting VBScript. What version of IE are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry. Version 11.0

Comment: @FranciscoJurado I don't think it supports VBScript buddy... Tough luck. Go back to Windows 98. `:(` Not kidding.

Comment: I got it working! IE10 and older versions support VBScript, so I just changed the IE11 compatibility to 10: